# How tu run Android Generic System Image (GSI) on qemu-aarch64?

Tags: linux, virtualization, android, operating-systems, qemu

Android [GSI](https://developer.android.com/topic/generic-system-image/releases) contains a `system.img` and a `vbmeta.img`. I tried `qemu-system-aarch64 system.img -machine virt` but qemu simply hangs.

If we can directly run the offical pre-built android image, creating an android VM would be much more easier. Could you provide some info about how to use the GSI image with qemu?

Comment: GSI images are not a full system, it can only be used on "Treble-compliant" devices. For an emulator this means you still require a base system containing all the hardware dependent parts.